# Ecto - Merge results based on common key?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have this query:

```
query = from(p in Tree,
        join: kw in assoc(p, :kw),
        join: k in Keyo, on: k.id == kw.keyo_id,
        where: p.user_id == ^id,
           select: %{
           tree: p.name,
           keyword: k.keyword,              
            },
        )
```

And it returns result like:

```
[%{keyword: "jesus", tree: "baila"}, %{keyword: "clinton", tree: "baila"},
 %{keyword: "bush", tree: "baila"}, %{keyword: "red", tree: "default"},
 %{keyword: "sea", tree: "default"}, %{keyword: "apple", tree: "default"}]
```

Is it possible to make database return results with the same column name somehow grouped together? Something similar to:

```
%{
 baila: [%{keyword: "jesus"}, %{keyword: "clinton"},
 %{keyword: "bush"}

 default: [%{keyword: "red"},
 %{keyword: "sea"}, %{keyword: "apple"}] 
}
```

Comment: I'm not certain, but `group_by/3` might provide what you're looking for. https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#group_by/3

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty easy to make just using the Elixir standard library! [`Enum.group_by/3`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html#group_by/3) would allow you to accomplish your goal. Using your example, it'd look something like this:

```
my_data = [%{keyword: "jesus", tree: "baila"},
           %{keyword: "clinton", tree: "baila"},
           %{keyword: "bush", tree: "baila"},
           %{keyword: "red", tree: "default"},
           %{keyword: "sea", tree: "default"},
           %{keyword: "apple", tree: "default"}]
IO.inspect Enum.group_by(my_data, &(&1.tree))
```

[Elixir Playground Source](http://elixirplayground.com?gist=d6e0e727e434c7597f07f5f122eb47b5)

Hope this helps!